# Is sqlite suitable for a mobile application that needs to transfer information from one user to another? If not, what database would be appropriate?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I'm new to android development so I don't have a lot of experience. I am writing an application for a sewing workshop for two types of users: a technologist and a seamstress. The technologist sends the task to the seamstress. Is a sqlite suitable for such an application, or is it better to choose another one? If so, which one?

I have so far tried to write only simple applications where there was no need to use a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.  The problem is you don't just need a database.  You also need a webservice in front of that database.  The database can't just be on the device, because it needs to share data between the seamstress and technologist.  That requires a DB in the cloud, and a webservice to protect access to that.

The DB can be SQLite, there's no reason that can't work.  But in general it isn't-  you generally would use MySQL, Posgres, or another open source db for this.  SQLite is generally used where you need a local on device db and top performance is not a concern.  For example storing data downloaded previously to your mobile phone.  The other solutions perform much better, and will scale if you need to increase capacity in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And can you advise where to start learning how to make a web server or maybe some links, otherwise I'm completely new to this

Comment: For something like this?  Start by picking a language you want to write it in, then find a framework in that language.  You don't want to write it from scratch

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation is to learn how to use Firebase database. You can store and retrive data with Realtime Database or Firestore Database using a data class, an adapter, a view model and a repository.
You can start with this video: https://youtu.be/MFcMw9jJA9o

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).